# Play HTML5 Video when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

Is there anyway to autoplay a HTML5 video only when the user has the video (or a certain percentage of the video) in the browser viewport?

Comment: You can have a div with display none...and if the age of that person is correct then add the video tag with the video source in the div and change the display to block....if this is what you want i could help you...simple show me the way you want to retrieve the age of the visitor and that's it xD

Answer (score 31):

## In brief

Let's say our browser window `W` currently scrolled to y-position `scrollTop` and `scrollBottom`

Our video will NOT be played when its position is at `V1` or `V2` as below snapshot.

[image]

## Code details

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Get media - with autoplay disabled (audio or video)
            var media = $('video').not("[autoplay='autoplay']");
            var tolerancePixel = 40;

            function checkMedia(){
                // Get current browser top and bottom
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + tolerancePixel;
                var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - tolerancePixel;

                media.each(function(index, el) {
                    var yTopMedia = $(this).offset().top;
                    var yBottomMedia = $(this).height() + yTopMedia;

                    if(scrollTop < yBottomMedia && scrollBottom > yTopMedia){ //view explaination in `In brief` section above
                        $(this).get(0).play();
                    } else {
                        $(this).get(0).pause();
                    }
                });

                //}
            }
            $(document).on('scroll', checkMedia);
        });
```

Comment: Please explain your answers instead of posting a wall of code.

Comment: Mikkel's solution is explained in the commented out text. It's elegant and it works. Plus I like that it uses jQuery. Thanks Mikkel!

Comment: I did adding the explanation for @MikkelJensen great answer

Comment: That's great, it's helped me a lot! It's no biggie but is there a way to make `tolerancePixel` a percentage? Also is it possible to display a "play again" button once the video has finished?

Answer (score 19):

hope this helps but it has been answered before

http://jsfiddle.net/jAsDJ/

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"),
fraction = 0.8;
function checkScroll() {

    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

        var video = videos[i];

        var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
            b = y + h, //bottom
            visibleX, visibleY, visible;

            visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
            visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

            visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

            if (visible > fraction) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }

    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a new API for this scenario, called [Intersection_Observer_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), which
Chrome 51+ and Edge 15+ has supported.

```
var options = {
    root: document.querySelector('.scroll-container'),
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0 // trigger only when element comes into view completely
};
var ob = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries[0].target.classList.toggle('red');
}, options);

// observe all targets, when coming into view, change color
document.querySelectorAll('.target').forEach((item) => {
    ob.observe(item);
});
```

Here is a simple demo:
https://codepen.io/hectorguo/pen/ybOKEJ

Answer (score 6):

You can use [window.pageXOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollX) and [window.pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY) to check how far your browser window is scrolled both vertically and horizontally. Use these with `window.innerWidth` and `innerHeight` and some basic geometry math to calculate how much your visible page overlaps with the video itself. Put this all in a function that you can attach to the `scroll` and `resize` event on the window object to run the check every time the scrolling changes.

Here is some sample code:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    info = document.getElementById('info'),
    fraction = 0.8;

function checkScroll() {
  var x = video.offsetLeft,
      y = video.offsetTop,
      w = video.offsetWidth,
      h = video.offsetHeight,
      r = x + w, //right
      b = y + h, //bottom
      visibleX,
      visibleY,
      visible;

  if (window.pageXOffset >= r ||
      window.pageYOffset >= b ||
      window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth < x ||
      window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight < y
     ) {    

    info.innerHTML = '0%';
    return;
  }

  visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
  visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

  visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

  info.innerHTML = Math.round(visible * 100) + '%';

  if (visible > fraction) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

//one time at the beginning, in case it starts in view
checkScroll();

//as soon as we know the video dimensions
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', checkScroll, false);
```

And a [working example](http://jsbin.com/ocupor/1/edit).

This code assumes a pretty simple page layout. If your video is positioned absolutely inside another element that has "position: relative" set, then you'll need to do a little more work to calculate the correct position of the video. (The same goes if the video has been moved with CSS transforms.)

Comment: I was assuming that the question was to play once a certain percentage of the video was downloaded.  I didn't read it that closely I guess

Comment: Yes. You can use `$` instead of getElementById, and `$('#video').bind(...` instead of addEventListener. You can use ".offset()" if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This pure javascript solution worked for me:

```js
// is visible function
function isVisible(elem) {
  if (!(elem instanceof Element)) throw Error('DomUtil: elem is not an element.');
  const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
  if (style.display === 'none') return false;
  if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;
  if (style.opacity < 0.1) return false;
  if (elem.offsetWidth + elem.offsetHeight + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
      elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0) {
      return false;
  }
  const elemCenter   = {
      x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
      y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  if (elemCenter.x < 0) return false;
  if (elemCenter.x > (document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth)) return false;
  if (elemCenter.y < 0) return false;
  if (elemCenter.y > (document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight)) return false;
  let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(elemCenter.x, elemCenter.y);
  do {
      if (pointContainer === elem) return true;
  } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
  return false;
}

// on window load start checking on scroll 
window.onload = function() {
  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video")
  function checkScroll() {
      for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
          var video = videos[i];
          if(isVisible(video)){
            video.play();
          }else{
            video.pause()
          }
      }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

}
```

isVisible function is from other solution: [answer for checking visible elements on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41698614/10138025)