# Play video only when scrolled into view

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

On this side scrolling page https://happyprime01.worldsecuresystems.com/video-test.html there is a video on the third and fourth page/panel. I want the video in the third panel to only start playing once the panel is in view. I have the following which uses the jquery.appear plugin mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119420/html5-video-play-once-scrolled-into-view?rq=1)

But I can not get it to work. Below is what I am trying. Can anybody assist with this please?

```
    <div id="item3" class="item">                   

            <!--video fills page section -->
            <div class="fullscreen-bg">
                <video id="vid-P" muted poster="img/bg-dynamically.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video  video-powder">
                    <source src="img/PowderPuff.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>                                             

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>

    <script>

        var myVideo = document.getElementById('vid-P');

    //when div with id item3 is in view play video
   $('#item3').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {


        if (appear) {
              // element is now visible in the viewport
             $("#item3").on('appear', myVideo.play);
            } else {
              // element has gone out of viewport
             $("#item3").on('disappear', myVideo.pause);
            }
  });


    </script>
```

Comment: I *believe* the correct usage is `$("#item3").on('appear', myVideo.play)` and `$("#item3").on('disappear', myVideo.pause)`

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this, I appreciate it heaps! I tried your idea (similar to the suggestion below), neither have worked for me yet, hopefully am close. I have updated my script above based on what you both are suggesting. can you see where I am going wrong still?

Comment: I've managed to getting working but ended up going with the approach shown here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vissense/tutorials/autoplay-video  - thanks again for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach shown on this site worked for me https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vissense/tutorials/autoplay-video  Similar to the above, but this worked straight away for me.

```
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    VisSense.VisMon.Builder(VisSense(myVideo, { fullyvisible: 0.75 }))
    .on('fullyvisible', function(monitor) {
      myVideo.play();
    })
    .on('hidden', function(monitor) {
      myVideo.pause();

    })
    .build()
    .start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define `appear` anywhere in the code, so `if (appear) {` will fail because your condition `appear = undefined`.

You can use the `appear` and `disappear` events instead:

```
 $('#item3').on('appear', myVideo.play)
            .on('disappear', myVideo.pause);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for looking at this for me, I appreciate it! I've updated the above based on what I think you meant but it's not working still. Was what I have now what you meant? I have tried your code without the if/else statements as well but that didn't work either.

Comment: This worked for me in the end  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vissense/tutorials/autoplay-video  - thanks again for your attention on this, it was helpful