# Play sticky HTML video based on window position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, html5-video

So I have 2 columns on my page. In the left column, I have 3 paragraphs. In the right column, I have 3 videos inside a sticky container.

My sticky container will remain stationary while the user scrolls but it should play a different video based on what paragraph the user is reading.

I am trying to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395920/play-html5-video-when-scrolled-to) but it is not working.

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="illustration">
            <div class="gif-container">
                <video class="gif" id="gif2" src="/GIF3.mp4" muted="muted"></video>
                <video class="gif" id="gif2" src="/GIF2.mp4" muted="muted"></video>
                <video class="gif" id="gif1" src="/GIF1.mp4" muted="muted"></video>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
            <p class="par" id="par1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <h1>Paragraph 2</h1>
            <p class="par" id="par2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <h1>Paragraph 3</h1>
            <p class="par" id="par3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

function checkPos(){

    let p = $('p');
    let media = $('video');
    let offset = 40;

    let windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + offset;

    p.each(function(index) {
        let parTop = $(this).offset().top;

        if ( windowBottom > parTop ) {
            media.get(index).play();
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('scroll', checkPos);

});
```

The error comes from using `.each()`'s index to select and play the relevant video. I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`.
However, `index` is a number and when I type the index manually (0, 1 or 2), my code works.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, the fix was actually very simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


function checkPos(){

    let p = $('p');
    let media = $('video');
    let offset = 40;

    let windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - offset;

    p.each(function(index) {
        let parTop = $(this).offset().top;
        // Create a new variable for index
        let i = index;

        if ( windowBottom > parTop ) {
            media.get(i).play();
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('scroll', checkPos);

});
```